# How can I break a symbolic link loop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, symbolic-link, infinite-loop

While I was trying to compile a C shared object library, I accidentally created two symbolic links which point to each other. Is there a way to get rid of them without nuking the whole directory? I read that the only way to break a symbolic link is to delete the file it points to, but I'm sure there must be another way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then delete the file it po... oh god. How did you manage this? :P

Comment: It is easy to do, and even easier to fix. Simlinks point at a filename, and the target filename does not even have to exist. And rm removes the simlink, not the file it points to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not a problem to delete symbolic links.  I'm not sure why you think that you need to delete the file the link points to.

Just delete them. Try this:

```
ln -s thing1 thing2   # thing1 does not exist
ln -s thing2 thing1   # circular reference
rm thing1 thing2      # no problem
```

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I can delete both links simultaneously with `rm`. Why did someone say I had to delete the target file...

Comment: `unlink` is even nicer than `rm` to remove links safely.

Comment: You could have even just deleted one of the simlinks and left the other - if you had any reason to.

Answer (score 3):

When you delete a symbolic link in Linux, the link is deleted and not the target file.